# Jquery spreadsheet or "data table" that can be edited without a DB?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm looking for a plugin that would allow for multiple users to add or delete table rows of data without the use of a database. This would be run locally, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Adding and deleting rows is easy, but do you want to save the changes anywhere? What do you mean by "run locally"? Please clarify exactly what you want to do.

Comment: You can use any file, as long as you have structure in the file that is discernible. This is done with XML commonly.

Comment: Hi guys. Yeah, I want the data to be saved on a local shared drive. The web application (that will be stored on each persons pc) will retrieve that file to get data, and save additional data to it when users save. The reason I'm doing this weird thing is that I want it for our local office where they won't give us an actual database to use for applications like Ms Access (which we won't get funding for, and Open Source applications are barred).

Comment: Imagine a normal MySQL table where you can add or delete rows of data to be saved. I'm basically trying to do that without the MySQL part. - however it must be able to support multiple users editing things at once since the source file will be shared on a local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look jStorage
http://www.jstorage.info/#example